# AS3 Get local folder mp3 contents into Array - Randomize

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, mp3, file-get-contents

### 50 RANDOM QUOTES

Looking to create an AS3 air for android app that loops through folders and 
randomly selects from all the mp3s in a folder and plays one of them. After
it is done playing it will go to the next folder and  do the same until it has 
finished playing 50 random quotes.

### FOR EXAMPLE:

1. The code would start with A1 and open folder 01 and randomly play one of the 10 mp3s.
2. When audio is over it would open folder 02 and randomly play one of the 7 mp3s.
3. After looping through all folders in A1 it would do the same thing all over in A2 - A5...

**WHAT I REALLY NEED HELP WITH IS...**

```
Using AS3 how do I select the contents of local folder  or sub 
folder and put them into an array and randomly choose one
from that array?
```

If I know how to do that then I can use this for the audio files and later apply this
same structure to call 50 random images.

NOTE The loop has to go in this order for a reason I will not explain here.

I included an IMAGE so you can visualize what I am trying to do.

---

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code gets contents of the folders.

```
import flash.filesystem.File;

var desktop:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("TheFilePathYouChoose/Choice");
var files:Array = desktop.getDirectoryListing();
for (var i:uint = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
 trace(files[i].nativePath); // gets the path of the files
 trace(files[i].name);// gets the name

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every `Folder` object in AS3 has a [documents](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/com/adobe/icc/vo/Folder.html#documents) property, which is of type `ArrayCollection`, a class from which you can access the `.length` and then randomly select a file from index 0 to `.length - 1`. Then push the path of the file onto your playlist array. Each `File` object has a `.nativePath` property, which is what you should use for the path. Then just instruct your player to play the paths in whatever order you want.

You *are* using AIR, right? This won't work in ordinary Flash.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am a bit lost as I am new to the file contents. Can you post a working example if you have a moment?

Comment: You can view all the AS3 documentation [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html). There are many examples of the use of each class.

Comment: Thanks for the right direction. It's a bit much for me to figure this  out  at this point. That site has always confused me.